# Ruby on Rails Javascript Runtime Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js

I've added execjs and therubyracer to my gemfile already and downloaded node.js but I'm still getting this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.1.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.1.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.1.1
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.1.1
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Simon/Documents/rails_projects/first_app/config/applicatio
n.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5
/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5
/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Great question, I just had the exact same problem